Power Automate HTTP Call to another flow with manual trigger not working
So, I've created 2 flows the calling flow (A) and the receiving flow (B). Both use a When HTTP Request Is Received trigger.
flow A sends a JSON object to flow B.
the call looks like this:

So, the problem is, that the Body is not being sent to flow B.

But the weird thing is, that it is working when I call flow B from Postman:
I get a 202 Accepted response and flow B runs normally.
Any help is much appreciated.
I've tried adding Content-Type and Accept Headers, but no luck.

So, it turns out that you need to turn off "Content Transfer" in the Settings of the HTTP Request.
